# I want to get the value of Drop down if Drop down consists of only one value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of Drop down if Drop down consists of only one value

```js
var select1 = document.getElementById("imgrp");
select1.options.length = 0;
var select = document.getElementById("irigmdtype");
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.text = option.value = trsetdata.d.results[0].Mdtyp;
select.add(option);
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: can you show a sample value thats accepted and not accepted

Comment: if you want to know the length of select or combo var length = $('#SelectList > option').length

Comment: bascically drop down consists of one value i.e,, Apple i want to get that value in alert box

Comment: U can use    $('#SelectList ').val()

Comment: if you have to chose from the list of option like jus one value from list of options then you can use for loop